# $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ independent identically distributed random variables $X_1\sim U(0,1)$. Define $Y_{n}= (\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i})^{-\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ be independent identically distributed random variables, $X_{1} \sim U(0,1)$. Define the variable

$$Y_{n}= \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}\right)^{-\frac{1}{n}}.$$

Does there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $\sqrt {n} (Y_{n}-a) \rightarrow  N\sim (0,b)$?

My attempt:

$$\ln(Y_{n})=-\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln (X_{i})\right).$$

Then $-\ln (X_{i}) \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$.

Also $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-\ln X_{i}) \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n,1)$.

I think I'm near the answer but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $\tau_n=\frac{\left(-\ln(X_1)\right)+\dots + \left(-\ln(X_n)\right)}{n}$ and use central limit theorem to get $$\sqrt{n}\left(\tau_n-1\right)\longrightarrow_{d}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ Apply the delta method with $f(x)=e^x$ to get $$\sqrt{n}\left(f(\tau_n)-f(1)\right)\longrightarrow _{d}\mathcal{N}\left(0,(f'(1))^2\right)$$ But $Y_n=f(\tau_n)$ and so $$\sqrt{n}\left(Y_n-e\right)\longrightarrow_{d}\mathcal{N}(0,e^2)$$

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking something similar with Delta method.